# Is there a way to update URI link of a local image, after a rotation?

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I wonder, as the title says, if it is possible to update an URI link of a local image after rotating the image of 270°. I have try this, but it doesn't seems to work (the image shown in the div 'img_displayed' is indeed rotated, but not on the plot made by plotly.

```
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.addEventListener("load", function(e) {

        document.getElementById('img_displayed').style.transform = "rotate(270deg)";
        document.getElementById('img_displayed').src = e.target.result;

        //Put the img file in the background
        let update = {
            images: [
            {
                source: `${document.getElementById('img_displayed').src}`,
                xref: "x",
                yref: "y",
                sizing: "stretch",
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                sizex: 18541,
                sizey: 18537,
                opacity: 0.6,
                xanchor: "left",
                yanchor: "bottom",
                layer: "below"
            }]
        }
        Plotly.relayout(GRAPHDIV, update);
    });
    FR.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("img_file").files[0]);
```

Does someone have a clue on where is my error here ?